# Split two array & combing it to one in js

Tags: javascript

I have two input variable with same name, below no. of div can be more

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="one[]">
  <input type="text" name="two[]">
</div>
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="one[]">
  <input type="text" name="two[]">
</div>
```

I am fetching above two textbox in two variable in JavaScript, below is code;

```
 var one =  $('input[name="one[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(',');

 var two =  $('input[name="two[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(',');
```

I want below result, because first div input box variable should be send together.

```
var three = $a,1$b,2
```

Anyone can let me know..???

Comment: does that sequence has any logic ?

Comment: `var three = $a,1$b,2$c,3` what is that meant to be? Is it a string? An array of some sort?

Comment: None of variables is an array, so your title doesn't match description, please update your description to properly explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a breakdown that handles if either array is longer than the other:

```
const one = 'a,b,c'
const two = '1,2,3,4,5'

// split strings by ',' to create arrays
const oneArray = one.split(',')
const twoArray = two.split(',')

// use reduce to accumulate while iterating
const final = oneArray.reduce((all, item, i) => {
    console.log(`CURRENT ${i}:`, '[one: ' + item + ']', '[two: ' + twoArray[i] + ']')

    // take the first element of the two array and put it right after
    // the first element of the one array
    if (item && twoArray[i]) all.push(item, twoArray[i])

    // if there is no elements left in the two array,
    // add the rest of the one array
    if (item && !twoArray[i]) all.push(item)

    // if we are at the last element in the one array,
    // add the rest of the two array to the end 
    if ((i === oneArray.length - 1) && (twoArray.length > oneArray.length)) {
        // this merges in the end of the two array
        return all.concat(twoArray.slice(i + 1))
    }
    return all
}, [])

// return final result
console.log(final)
```

Here is the clean final:

```
const one = 'a,b,c'
const two = '1,2,3,4,5'
const oneArray = one.split(',')
const twoArray = two.split(',')

const alternateMerge = (oneArray, twoArray) => oneArray.reduce((all, item, i) => {
  if (item && twoArray[i]) all.push(item, twoArray[i])
  if (item && !twoArray[i]) all.push(item)
  if ((i === oneArray.length -1) && (twoArray.length > oneArray.length)) {
    return all.concat(twoArray.slice(i+1))
  }
  return all
}, [])

console.log(alternateMerge(oneArray, twoArray))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have jQuery and pure JS versions as below:

```js
var one = "a,b,c";
var two = "1,2,3";

var oneArray = one.split(/,/).map(e => '$' + e);
var twoArray = two.split(/,/).map(e => ',' + e);

var three_jQuery = $.map(oneArray, function(v, i) { return [v, twoArray[i]]; });

var three_pureJS = oneArray.reduce((arr, v, i) => arr.concat(v, twoArray[i]), []);

console.log(three_jQuery.join(''));
console.log(three_pureJS.join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

to achieve the exact result of your problem I would do as follows:

```
var one = "1,2,3";
var two = "a,b,c";
var newOne = a.split(','); // ["1","2","3"]
var newTwo = b.split(','); // ["a","b","3"]
var three = '';

for(var i = 0; i < newOne.length; i++) {
   three += '$' + newOne[i] + ',' + newTwo[i]; //the result would be "$a,1$b,2$c,3"
}
```